# Date from week date format: 2022-W02-1 (ISO 8601)

Tags: apache-spark, date, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark3

Having a date, I create a column with [ISO 8601 week date format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date):

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([('2019-03-18',), ('2019-12-30',), ('2022-01-03',), ('2022-01-10',)], ['date_col'])

df = df.withColumn(
    'iso_from_date',
    F.concat_ws(
        '-',
        F.expr('extract(yearofweek from date_col)'),
        F.lpad(F.weekofyear('date_col'), 3, 'W0'),
        F.expr('weekday(date_col) + 1')
    )
)
df.show()
# +----------+-------------+
# |  date_col|iso_from_date|
# +----------+-------------+
# |2019-03-18|   2019-W12-1|
# |2019-12-30|   2020-W01-1|
# |2022-01-03|   2022-W01-1|
# |2022-01-10|   2022-W02-1|
# +----------+-------------+
```

**Using Spark 3**, how to get back the date, given ISO 8601 week date?

I tried the following, but it is both, incorrect and uses `LEGACY` configuration which I don't like.

```py
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy", "LEGACY")
df.withColumn('date_from_iso', F.to_date('iso_from_date', "YYYY-'W'ww-uu")).show()
# +----------+-------------+-------------+
# |  date_col|iso_from_date|date_from_iso|
# +----------+-------------+-------------+
# |2019-03-18|   2019-W12-1|   2019-03-18|
# |2019-12-30|   2020-W01-1|   2019-12-30|
# |2022-01-03|   2022-W01-1|   2021-12-27|
# |2022-01-10|   2022-W02-1|   2022-01-03|
# +----------+-------------+-------------+
```

I am aware of the possibility to create a `udf` which works:

```py
import datetime
@F.udf('date')
def iso_to_date(iso_date):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(iso_date, '%G-W%V-%u')

df.withColumn('date_from_iso', iso_to_date('iso_from_date')).show()
```

But I am looking for a more efficient option. The ideal option should not use `LEGACY` configuration and be translatable to SQL or Scala (no inefficient `udf`).

Comment: This format will convert the 2019's date correctly. `YYYY-'W'ww-uu`.  However I think the 2022's week number is not correct according to https://www.timeanddate.com/date/weeknumber.html.  Spark's offset of weekofyear is different?

Comment: @Emma - thanks for the response. This is a very interesting observation! I really don't know why doesn't it work. As can be seen, Spark perfectly forms ISO format from the date. So at least in that part it knows how to do the calculations... I will edit my question using your format, as it seems more appropriate than mine, but still does not work.

Comment: I also found https://mungingdata.com/apache-spark/week-end-start-dayofweek-next-day/  For `weekofyear` function, "Week starts with Monday and ends with Sunday (other Spark functions assume week starts with Sunday and ends with Saturday)"   I think the behavior you are seeing is something related to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PySpark, I have found a nicer than `udf` option. This will use `pandas_udf` which is vectorized (more efficient):

```py
import pandas as pd
@F.pandas_udf('date')
def iso_to_date(iso_date: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    return pd.to_datetime(iso_date, format='%G-W%V-%u')

df.withColumn('date_from_iso', iso_to_date('iso_from_date')).show()
# +----------+-------------+-------------+
# |  date_col|iso_from_date|date_from_iso|
# +----------+-------------+-------------+
# |2019-03-18|   2019-W12-1|   2019-03-18|
# |2019-12-30|   2020-W01-1|   2019-12-30|
# |2022-01-03|   2022-W01-1|   2022-01-03|
# |2022-01-10|   2022-W02-1|   2022-01-10|
# +----------+-------------+-------------+
```

It works in Spark 3 without the `LEGACY` configuration. So it's acceptable.

However, there is room for improvement, as this option is not transferable to SQL or Scala.